# Communication between Cordova iOS app and Apple watch

Tags: cordova, apple-watch

We have a cordova app and we are working on supporting Apple watch. I understand we can't run the cordova apps directly on Apple watch, since there is no webkit on Apple Watch. But the apps on Apple Watch just seems to mirror what ever is pushed from the Mobile .i.e, most of the processing is expected to happen on Mobile. So I was hoping that I could reuse some of local database layer, server communications and business logic created in Cordova app. For this I believe I need to establish the communication between the mobile app and watch app. Also I believe the mobile app needs to be active if I need to call any javascript functions that are available in the mobile app. Is there any way to call the javascript functions from the Apple Watch when the mobile app is in background or is inactive.

Comment: try this plugin https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-apple-watch

Comment: @jcesarmobile, will this work if the mobile app is not launched ?

Comment: I don't know, it's for communication between the app and the watch, so I don't think it can communicate if the app is closed, but didn't try

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can reuse your phone app and even build the Watch UI with Javascript. By using this plugin: http://plugins.telerik.com/cordova/plugin/applewatch

And if the phone app is closed or in the background the Watch app has no problems fetching data from it.